# Instanciar tipo genérico de um Enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Gostaria de instanciar uma classe vinda de um Enum, por exemplo:

Ao invés de fazer:

```
var classeGenerica;

if (viewModel.tipoCarro == 1)
   classeGenerica = new classeCarro();
else
   classeGenerica = new classeOutros();
```

Algo que fosse mais ou menos assim:

```
TipoCarroEnum genericoEnum = (TipoCarroEnum)tipoCarro;
var generico = new genericoEnum();
```

Comment: Não entendi. Você quer usar um `Enum` para instânciar uma classe? Você não pode instanciar um `Enum`.

Comment: queria converter ele em tipo ou objeto para poder instanciar

Comment: Pra que? O que você quer pegar duma suposta instância dum `Enum`? Um enumerador é nada mais que uma classe abstrata onde cada valor dentro representa um `int`.

Comment: pra evitar de fazer um if pra cada tipo

Comment: Faz um `switch` se quiser atribuir cada valor do `enum` para uma classe específica. Ou se quiser, você pode usar o `Enum.Parse()` mas ele não se enquadra na sua situação. Realmente não faz sentido querer instanciar um `enum`, além de ser impossível, você na verdade irá estar instanciando um número inteiro, e não uma classe.

Comment: Entendi o que você quer fazer. Em outras linguagens seria um trabalho mais fácil. Dá uma olhada em implementações do Factory Pattern pra C#, talvez te dê algumas ideias.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode trocar os "ifs" por switch case.

Exemplo:

```
//Enum com os tipos de carros
public enum CarroEnum
{
    BMW = 1,
    Ford = 2,
    Audi = 3,
    Toyota = 4
}

//--------------Implementação do enum

//O Enum utilizado neste exemplo será o CarroEnum.Audi
var tipoCaroo = CarroEnum.Audi;

switch (tipoCaroo)
{
    case CarroEnum.Audi:
        //Instancia classe referente ao carro Audi
        break;

    case CarroEnum.BMW:
        //Instancia classe referente ao carro BMW
        break;

    case CarroEnum.Ford:
        //Instancia classe referente ao carro Ford
        break;

    case CarroEnum.Toyota:
        //Instancia classe referente ao carro Toyota
        break;

    default:
        //Caso não entre nos cases acima, cairá aqui.
        break;
}
```